# How to run two WAR files in same worklight server?

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, war

I want to run two different WAR files in same Worklight server. I came know it is possible from this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_configure_appserver_reference.html). But want to know how to achieve this?

1. How to change the context root path of war file while
   building? 
   This [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_multiple_wl_servers_with_wl_studio.html) explains only to change the context root for local development environment. But i want to run it in one of the testing servers.
2. Do i need to mention context root while deploying? -
   Currently after building ill send the war files to other team to
   deploy. They do have a ant script to deploy the war into server.
3. Let me know do i need to take care of anything else while running 2 wars in same server.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Worklight Studio you will have 2 Worklight projects. Each Worklight project will have its own .war file (in the \bin folder). By default, the context root of each project is the name of the project.

These .war files are separate of each other. They run separate of each other whether you are running in Worklight Studio or outside of it.

Outside of Eclipse Worklight Studio, you are not deploying the .war files to the Worklight Server.

You are deploying the .war files to the application server (WAS, Liberty, Tomcat) that Worklight Server is also deployed to it.

So pointing to `http://worklightserver/contextRootA` will be the first project, and pointing to `http://worklightserver/contextRootA` will be the second project

Comment: but for my case i want to run the same project with two different war  in same server?

Comment: So that's still the same... create 2 Worklight projects, give them different names. Deploy.

Comment: Created 2 projects with different name, took war files from bin and deployed in same application server. But it is taking `http://worklightserver/worklight` as context root. I guess am missing to set the context root.

Comment: right-click on app folder > run as > build settings and deploy target

Comment: am using 6.0 so i couldn't find that option. but however i want `Build the application to work with a different Worklight Server` option only in 6.0.

Comment: in Worklight 6.0, right-click on the PROJECT and select "change worklight target server".

Comment: i used "change work light target server" It is working fine with local development environment. But not with testing server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53820/discussion-between-bluewings-and-idan-adar)